# Add logo to a map using Leaflet/Mapbox

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

I am currently trying to learn how to use **Leaflet** / **Mapbox** (and *JS*, to some extent) by creating custom test maps.

My problem is that I want to **add a logo** on the top of my map, with **absolute coordinates** (in **pixels**).

I have already looked for out-of-the-box methods on the API reference and GIS stack, but couldn't find anything. I also tried some "homemade" solutions (with my limited skills), like adding the logo as a marker or custom layer with non-fixed geographic coordinates (using getBounds().getEast() for example). Unfortunately, nothing worked...

It can be easily done with the *Google Maps API*, using :

```
var controlUI = document.createElement('div')
```

and the logo passed as a background for the 'div' section, but I would like to avoid this API.

Here is an example of what I want it to look like :

[image: Google Maps handling a logo]

Comment: `document.createElement()` is a standard Javascript function, it's not a part of the Google Maps API/framework https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try with [L.Control.Credits](https://github.com/gregallensworth/L.Control.Credits) plugin.

> A simple, attractive, interactive control to put your logo and link in the corner of your map.

You can also easily do it yourself with JavaScript:

```js
var mapControlsContainer = document.getElementsByClassName("leaflet-control")[0];
var logoContainer = document.getElementById("logoContainer");

mapControlsContainer.appendChild(logoContainer);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3v7hd2vx/44/

Comment: Thanks ! The second solution is exactly what I was looking for, since the first one only allows for no more than 4 positions.

Answer (score 3):

You can use L.control, but there are only 4 positions:

```
    //logo position: bottomright, topright, topleft, bottomleft
    var logo = L.control({position: 'topleft'});
    logo.onAdd = function(map){
        var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'myclass');
        div.innerHTML= "<img src='logo.png'/>";
        return div;
    }
    logo.addTo(map);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works very well ! Unfortunately, 4 positions is quite limiting.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `div` logo inner `div` map in HTML:

```
<div id="map" style="...">
   <div id="logoContainer">
     <img src="img.png" width="70">
   </div>
</div>
```

And add a CSS:

```
#logoContainer {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    top: 15px;
    left: 15px;
}
```